# In C/C++ program, how is assigned the memory for the argument vector memory?

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, argv, argc

In C/C++ programs it is very common to find the main function written as:

```
int main( int argc, char *argv[] )
{
    ...
}
```

My questions about the memory used by argv:
In which moment is it reserved? at compilation or execution time?
How is it made?
How much memory is it reserved?
Is it possible to use the same technique for other variables in the program?

Comment: It is operating system specific. On Linux, read about the details of `execve`  system call

Answer (score 0):

### **My questions about the memory used by argv:**

The memory is used for command line arguments, when not using the operating systems command line there is no need for it. The main function below also works yet depends on the compiler, sometimes "NULL" needs to be inserted within main() for proper compilation. This may save a microscopic amount of memory if you don't need the command line. ;)

```
INT main()
{
    ... Not using (int argc, char *argv[]) is not too common though, most people type the command line arguments even when they don't use them. Strange I know, they must not know why they do what they do. ...
}
```

### **In which moment is it reserved? at compilation or execution time?**

"The parameters argc and argv and the strings pointed to by the argv array shall be modifiable by the program, and retain their last-stored values between program startup and program termination." C-Documentation: http://port70.net/~nsz/c/ "c89"

### **How is it made?**

Its made with a variable, and an array. Hence (int argc == a variable) (char *argv[] == *pointer aray)

### **How much memory is it reserved?**

I would say 4 bytes ... (int argc -> int 16bit) + (char *argv[] -> *pointer = 16bit) = 32bits ... lol, idk. The size of this array is not defined, depends if array is truly "byte sized", alignment, padding, ect.

### **Is it possible to use the same technique for other variables in the program?**

I'm sure you can add variables to main() if you choose, but that could be "implementation-defined". You can also obviously use *argv[] to store any program variables, because thats what its used for.

> ### **P.S.**
>
> This depends entirely on the operating system, you would need to dig into documentation of the compiler being used. Many broad questions, tune what you are asking I can get more specific if needed!! Hope I covered what you are asking about.

Comment: if the declaration char **v; is done, then v[0], v[1],... can be used for strings only after the proper allocation is done. What about a argv?

Comment: Are you replacing "char *argv[]" with "char **v" :
    - main( int argc, char **v )
Not using "char argc" at all, you didn't mention it :
    - main( char *argv[], char **v )
Appending it to the end with everything as such :
    - main( int argc, char *argv[], char **v )
Or are you talking about declaring main like so :
    - main( char **v, char *argv[] )
What is going inside of main(), how do you plan to use it?!

Comment: no, I am not replacing v with argv. I just dechared char **v; inside the main(int argc, char *argv[] ) function for pointing out the differences between the behaviors of v and argv.

Comment: The first index of argv[] is 0, holds program name. In command prompt, when I navigate to programs containing folder, type name of program, hit enter, it will run. Or I can type name, hit space, to pass it a second argument "like a file name" it is passed to argv[] as index 1. Stuff part of [ main(*PartHere*) ] is intended to interact with the OS in some way, stuff outside/inside/after [ *Outside* main() { *Inside* } *After* ] is your programs memory. OS arguments passed to/from program is "suppose" to take place through argv[] the middle man. You may pass data from argv to v and vice versa.

Comment: My question regards about the memory used by argv.
As it is not explicitly allocated by the C programmer: (1) how much memory is it used for argv? and (2) Is it allocated at compilation time or at run time?

Comment: From the perspective of a C programmer. (1) Memory is memory. How much memory is that? however much the OS decides. (2) Anything that makes no use of malloc()/calloc() is assumed to be allocated at compilation time. You are explicitly asking for info, non-explicitly. What type of memory: CPU-Memory/Cache, Ram, HDD?? The whole program is technically "allocated" at run-time, from the saved byte-code on HDD that was complied when its run. Are you asking about what happens at hardware level?? C programming is soft-where level, execution details are abstracted, buried under every release/update.